# text color different in chrome/firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, colors

I have a bit of a problem with text color in chrome.
i am using a class in CSS:

```
.game_info{font-size:3; font-weight:bold; color:#000000;}
```

as you can see, i want the text color to be black. this works well for FF and IE, but in chrome i get a different color.

this is the HTML code:

```
<a class="game_info">
Achilles is an awsome online adventure game. Fight your enemies using spears, cutting heads of enemey and scaring them!
Very Bloody game! there are Survival mode and Normal Mode. ENJOY !</a>
```

you can view the page is http://www.sababagamesonline.com/Achilles.php

Yoni

Comment: Looks black to me in Chrome..

Comment: Yep, black for me in Chrome too.

Comment: The handy dandy color picker tool tells me that *is* black in Chrome, not just that it *looks* like black.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the class  `a.game_info{}`

Comment: Works but not sure why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing black text in FF and Chrome on the site you linked. Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Answer (score 0):

Using:

Windows XP SP 3

FF 3.6.13
Chrome 8.0.552.237
IE 7.0.5730.13

Black is applied in all browsers when inspecting the CSS applied using webtools. Hex colour finder is also showing black rendered in my browsers. Do have specific browser versions you are using? How are you determining the colours shown are different?

devmau5